# match target array value and get exact image caption to pull image id

Tags: php, wordpress

I have News API and Team API endpoints. Both API's needs to match ID to be able to get the `$TeamName` (ex. Jets) and then I will use `$TeamName` value to match it to my ACF Gallery `$image['caption']` value. From there, I can able to get the `$image['id']` or `$image['url']`.

```
foreach ( $newsLists as $newsList ) :
    $images = get_field('widget_gallery_'.$leagues[$news].'news', 'option');

    foreach ( $team_body as $team ) {

        // Compare News TeamID and Score TeamID
        if ( $newsList->TeamID != $team->TeamID )
            continue;

            $TeamName = $team->Name; // Get Team Name ex. Jets
    }

    foreach ( $images as $image ) {

        // Compare Team Name & Widget Gallery - Image Caption ex. (Jets == Jets)
        if ( $TeamName != $image['caption'] )
            continue;
            
            $TeamID = $image['id']; // Get Image ID
            $TeamCaption = $image['caption']; // Check Caption if Correct
    }

    // echo $TeamID;
    echo wp_get_attachment_image( $TeamID, 'news-img' ); 
endforeach;
```

From my code, I can see the value displaying it correctly, however from my gallery, it is incomplete. Meaning not all specific Team is there, so i've created a caption "default-1" image to alter and temporary place it there if there is no matching from `$TeamName` and `$image['caption']`.

[image: News Article]

**Question**

How can I eliminate those redundant values and replace it with my "default-1" id value? Or is there a better way for this?

Comment: I think I understand what you are doing, take a look at my answer and let me know if this is what you are looking for!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if the team name and caption don't match, the code does nothing so the team name and all other variables are kept as the old one:

```
// Compare Team Name & Widget Gallery - Image Caption ex. (Jets == Jets)
if ( $TeamName != $image['caption'] )
    continue;
```

You can change this so that if they don't match, the variables get set to your default value:

```
$defaultName    = "Default Team Name";
$defaultID      = "Default ID";
$defaultCaption = "Default Team Caption";

foreach ( $images as $image ) {

    // Compare Team Name & Widget Gallery - Image Caption ex. (Jets == Jets)
    if ( $TeamName != $image['caption'] ){
        $TeamName    = $defaultName;
        $TeamID      = $defaultID;
        $TeamCaption = $defaultImage;
    }
    else{    
        $TeamID      = $image['id']; // Get Image ID
        $TeamCaption = $image['caption']; // Check Caption if Correct
    }
}
```

Comment: hello, actually it didn't work.

im still puzzle in this: `if ( $image['caption'] != $TeamName ) continue; $TeamID = $image['id'];` which it display correctly all images, but if the succeeding post/article do not match the caption, it will use the last correct image from previous post/article.

Comment: @iMarkDesigns Your question only mentioned team names so that's all I set. You just need to set the default value for the image (and any other variables) in the `if` code. I've updated the answer to do this.

Comment: @iMarkDesigns Did the updated code in my answer work for you?